A user on jenkins isn't able to see the option "Build with parameters"
A user on jenkins isn't able to see the option "Build with parameters", this job was recently created.
What i've checked already:

The user is logged-in
The project is enabled
The user is able to run other jenkins jobs and see "Build" or "Build with parametrs" option on other jobs.
I've made the user "Owner" of the job by clicking in "Manage Ownership" still he is unable to see the build option.

What can i do next?
I'm not a jenkins admin, i've the same developer role as another user.

A lot of settings could be the cause. Please create another user and give the same permissions and share the result. Also share the plugins (related to authorization) and jenkins versions

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I've identified that the user has to be added in the roles of the project or jobs created

I've identified that the user has to be added in the roles of the project or jobs created. This needs to be done in "Manage Jobs" and then "Assign roles and responsibilities"
